# How to add custom font to NextJs 13 that is hosted on Cloudfront?

Tags: fonts, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I looked at `next/font` [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts), that is mainly focused on Google fonts or local fonts. Unfortunately, I can't have local fonts, they all needed to be hosted on Cloudfront that I have links to. Is there a way to use font links for `Font` component?